# Why does my create-react-app not showing on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I've created a react app using create-react-app. It is rendering and working properly on desktop browsers but on mobile browsers it will only link to my github project page. I have no idea why.

Here is the [live page](https://cwu023.github.io/project-8-react-giphy-gallery/#/) of the app.

Here is the [github page](https://github.com/cwu023/project-8-react-giphy-gallery) of the app.

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, that page seems to load fine! I have tested on both my desktop chrome/safari device emulators, and my personal iPhone!

That linked site `https://cwu023.github.io/project-8-react-giphy-gallery/` seems to load fine!

If you have more details let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I got it fixed and it didn't work simply because I didn't push it to my gh-page branch lol

Answer (score 0):

I tested here too and it is working.

Did you tried to clearing your browser cache??

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I got it fixed and it didn't work simply because I didn't push it to my gh-page branch lol